# Entry Parameter Box from VBA SQL

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a main table and another table that I want to place data where one field matches another.  The following code continues to ask me for a parameter but my WHERE clause should be answering that.

```
    For curRec = 1 To cnt
    
        'Reference table
        name = "tblMain"
    
        'Look up specific Angio type report from drop down on GUI
        angioType = Me.cboAngio_Rep.Value
        
        aType = DLookup("cbo_AngioType", "" & name, "ID = " & curRec)
                 
        'Insert data into one large table, tblAllReports
        strSql = "INSERT INTO tblAllReports (dt_Date, txt_Name, txt_MRN, dt_DOB, cbo_Gender, cbo_AngioType, cbo_InterVType, txt_Notes, cbo_Amen_To_Repair, dt_InterV_Date, dt_fu_Angio_Date, cbo_Rx, dt_fu_Lab_Date, dt_Stop_DAPT, cbo_MD, txt_Age) " & _
                 "SELECT dt_Date, txt_Name, txt_MRN, dt_DOB, cbo_Gender, cbo_AngioType, cbo_InterVType, txt_Notes, cbo_Amen_To_Repair, dt_InterV_Date, dt_fu_Angio_Date, cbo_Rx, dt_fu_Lab_Date, dt_Stop_DAPT, cbo_MD, txt_Age " & _
                 "FROM " & name & " " & _
                 "WHERE " & angioType & " = " & aType & " AND ID = " & curRec & ";"
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSql
                
    Next curRec
```

Have tried `Nz(Me.cboAngio_Rep)`, same results...

Comment: Possible, should be `` "WHERE  angioType  = " & aType & " AND ID = " & curRec & ";"`` or `` "WHERE  cbo_angioType = " & aType & " AND ID = " & curRec & ";"`` or  some other where clause. If angioType is string, for exmple "MyName", will be ask Enter value for MyName.

Comment: This error typically indicates a missing or misspelled field name.

Comment: All spelling was checked and is correct. angioType = the value in a drop down box. aType resolve to match that. Both are all spelled correctly. So the where should be comparing the two strings. Stepping through the code with the debugger, both resolve to the same value.

Comment: `name` is a reserved word. Suggest you not use it for other object or variable names. What field name is `angioType` set to? What data type? If text, need apostrophe delimiters for the aType input. You use prefixes like txt_ and cbo_ with field names in table?

Comment: angioType is defined above this as Dim angioType As String

Comment: Yes, a string that could be a field name so WHERE clause could compile as something like: `WHERE cbo_angioType='abc' AND ID=18`. If angioType is not passing a valid field name then certainly this SQL will fail.

Comment: I don't understand relevance of that last comment.

Comment: name was changed to tName

Comment: Fine, but that doesn't alter my comment about valid field name in SQL. Why would source table and field names be dynamic anyway?

Comment: All fields are valid. All hold strings. The two tables were updated. The GUI control is a drop down box. This code fires on a change.  If the selected text is "Treatment" then that is saved as angioType (Defined as a String). aType, also defined as a string is used for finding all entries in the main table that contain the same value as the selected value from angioType.  The WHERE clause should compare them. If they are equal, then it writes to the second table, if not, it should skip.  It runs but asks for a parameter to be entered that is equal to the one selected from the drop down.

Comment: They should be dynamic because I do not want to add code for each value in the drop down combo box.

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Comment: In my simple test, i get message (InputBox) with title "Input parameter value"  and message with  name of parameter and input box.  This ``name of parameter`` is value of ``angioType`` in your example. My table do not have sach field - in this case ``ask me for a parameter``. If variable angioType contains valid field name, query runs without InputBox.

Comment: I have an almost identical query that finds data between dates. That one work very well. This one, not so much. ALL data types have been checked and they are all the same. All names match. Literally stepping through the code and both values = the exact same thing. Yet the box still fires.

Comment: If you show in comment or in question your WHERE clause part of sqrSql, I would see confirmation or refutation of my hypothesis. My suggestion is quite simple - a non-existent field name in Where. WHERE FieldName1=11 AND Id=1. And InputBox with "Enter value of FieldName1".

Comment: `Debug.Print strSql` so you can see what the compiled SQL looks like. Again, the WHERE clause needs a field name in the conditional expression., not two identical data strings.